# What is the lifetime of the vasopressin receptor V2?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-signaling, receptor

I was looking at the production of vasopressin receptor 2, also known as V2R or ADH-R. What I found is that it is coded by the AVPR2 gene and degraded by the Alix protein [(source)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17287200).

But I did not get a sense of the timescale. After a receptor protein has been produced and embedded itself in the cell membrane, how long does it live? Is it days, weeks, months? Does it live until the cell dies or is it degraded before that?

Does the lifetime differ between each receptor, or on the cell type, or is it roughly the same for all G coupled receptors?

Comment: But where did you read about this particular example? Certainly we can find some additional information from that source. But in any case, the turnover of different GPCRs shouldn't be the same.. There is no strong reason to assume so.

Comment: @WYSIWYG This is the one study I found about V2R degradation, it is the one which concentrates on Alix.http://ajprenal.physiology.org/content/292/5/F1303 I don't remember where I got the info about the encoding gene, it was simply a table listing hypophyse hormones I found somewhere, and it had a column listing the gene.

Comment: Okay.. can you cite that article in the question?